# How to capture low resolution picture using android camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera-intent

I want to capture photo and also save it to my sdcard using android camera.I know its easy but I want to store image in low resolution without telling user go to setting and set low resolution manually.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913282/open-android-camera-in-lower-resolution-with-action-image-capture

Answer (score 2):

What i am gonna write is not good practice to do code but it may full-fill your requirement

- capture image as you do with normally using android default camera .
- check the path of that image which just now captured .
- reduce quality of that image as per requirement using [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) calss and store in [bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) object
- delete that original  image which captured by default camera
- save that bitmap object to SD Card where old image was located with same file name and path

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very late but this is for the people who might read this question now , you can use this following code :

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters = mcamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(sizes.size()-1);
        Log.d("Parth","Size : "+size.height+","+size.width);
        Log.d("Parth","Sizes:"+sizes.toString());
        parameters.setPictureSize(size.width,size.height);
        mcamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a camera app by yourself. Use `BitmapFactory` to decode raw data. Via `BitmapFactory.Options`, you can set any resolution you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to capture image :

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, preinsertedUri);
```

Don't use `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` because the image will be big size if you use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`