# android force intent to take low quality and low resolution photo

Tags: android, android-intent

I am launching an intent to take a photo. It is possible to force the camera activity to take the photo in the lower resolution and lower quality?

Comment: cant you do it after taking the picture?

Comment: yes, I would like to do it in the best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to set camera intent parameters to low-resolution.

You can:

1) take standart photo bitmap and resize it, as you need

2) implement your own camera activity and set camera parameters

See also:

[Open Android Camera in lower resolution with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913282/open-android-camera-in-lower-resolution-with-action-image-capture)

[App -> Camera -> Photo -> low resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021353/app-camera-photo-low-resolution)